# How do i include references to web services in NANT or csc.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nant, csc

Im trying to automate our build process. To do this i need to compile the app_code in a asp.Net website to a dll so i can run NUnit test against the code. Before you suggest that i just use a class library, i will say that i agree with you, my superiors however, take a different view and have vetoed the use of dlls in our web sites.

The problem i have is that the app_code classes reference web services. How do i get the csc task to include these when compiling the code into a class library? The nant target i have so far is:

```
<target name="Compile">
    <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5" />
    <csc target="library" output="DocSysAppCode.dll" debug="true">
      <sources>
        <include name="D:\Inetpub\DocSys\App_Code\Common\*.cs" />
        <include name="D:\Inetpub\DocSys\App_Code\DocSys\SiteLegislation.generated.cs" />
      </sources>
      <resources>
        <include name="D:\DocSysQueue\Web References\WS_DocSys\*.*" />
        <include name="D:\DocSysQueue\app.config" />
      </resources>
    </csc>
</target>
```

If there is another way of achieving my goals then please let me know.

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're most likely after is generating the web service proxy class and compiling that into into your project. To do this, have a look at the [wsdl](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/help/tasks/wsdl.html) task that is part of [NantContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net).

You'll be able to do something like the following:

```
<target name="generate-proxy"/>
    <wsdl path="${wsdl.url}" language="CS" namespace="svc" outfile="MyProxy.cs" verbose="true" />
</target>
```

You can then take the output of that task (MyProxy.cs) and compile it into your project.

```
<target name="Compile" depends="generate-proxy">
    <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5" />
    <csc target="library" output="DocSysAppCode.dll" debug="true">
      <sources>
        <include name="MyProxy.cs" />
        <include name="D:\Inetpub\DocSys\App_Code\Common\*.cs" />
        <include name="D:\Inetpub\DocSys\App_Code\DocSys\SiteLegislation.generated.cs" />
      </sources>
    </csc>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks, shortly after posting this question i discovered wsdl.exe

Comment: Is this a valid method for "Service References", in a .NET project? I am confused if I need to use a proxy class or actually reference the "Service Reference" object directly?

Comment: @devtron: The <wsdl> task is just for web services not the WCF based services that I assume you're referring to. WCF service references are  generated by the ServiceModel Metadata Utility (svcutil.exe). You could use the <exec> task to call out to svcutil.exe and take the output file that gets generated to include in the sources block (just like MyProxy.cs).